# drop multiple columns pySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using pyspark 2.4 version.

I have a weird issue with dropping columns after joining.

I get the correct result if I drop one column, but I get an error if I drop two columns.

I want to drop the 'address' and 'role' columns from the workers1 data frame on the joined data frame (joined_workers).

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

workers1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("barmen", "Paris", "25"),
    ("waitress", None, "22")],
    ["role", "address", "age"])

workers1.toPandas()

>>>
    role      address   age
0   barmen    Paris     25
1   waitress  None      22

workers2 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("barmen", "Paris"),
    (None, "Berlin")],
    ["role", "address"])

workers2.toPandas()

>>>
    role    address
0   barmen  Paris
1   None    Berlin

clumns_to_join_on = ["role", "address"]

joined_workers = workers1.alias("workers1").join(
    workers2.alias("workers2"),
    [
        *[getattr(workers1, col).eqNullSafe(
                getattr(workers2, col)) for col in clumns_to_join_on]
    ],
    how="right",
)

joined_workers.toPandas()

>>>
    role    address age     role    address
0   None    None    None    None    Berlin
1   barmen  Paris   25      barmen  Paris

# expected result

joined_workers.drop(*[f.col("workers1.role")]).toPandas()

>>>
    address age     role    address
0   None    None    None    Berlin
1   Paris   25      barmen  Paris

# Work as expected

joined_workers.drop(*[f.col("workers1.address")]).toPandas()

>>>
    role    age     role     address
0   None    None    None     Berlin
1   barmen  25      barmen   Paris

# Work as expected

joined_workers.drop(*[f.col("workers1.role"), f.col("workers1.address")]).toPandas()

>>>
TypeError: each col in the param list should be a string
```

Comment: Any specific reason for using col(name) instead of string?

Comment: joined_workers.drop(*["workers1.role", "workers1.address"]).toPandas()

this doesn't drop any column

Comment: Got it, it's not resolving the column by <df_alias>.<column_name>. The joining case select solution from my answer and let me know if you face any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Just select the columns you want to retain or select all columns except the one's to drop.

```
df.select([col for col in df.columns if col not in ['workers1.role', 'workers1.address']])
```

**Update:** In case of join with common column names:

```
joined_workers.select(["workers1."+col for col in workers1.columns if col not in ['role', 'address']]+["workers2."+col for col in workers2.columns if col not in [<if_any_from_2>]]).show()
```

Remove the second If condition from workers2.columns if all are to be retained from workers2 Dataframe

Comment: "Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o441.select.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'role' is ambiguous, could be: workers1.role, workers2.role.;"

Comment: @amit You used joined_workers.columns right in the loop?

Comment: @amit Added join solution

Comment: joined_workers.select([col for col in joined_workers.columns if col not in ['workers1.role', 'workers1.address']])

>>>

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o441.select.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'role' is ambiguous, could be: workers1.role, workers2.role.

Comment: @amit use the second solution

Comment: @amit Use joined_workers.select(["workers1."+col for col in workers1.columns if col not in ['role', 'address']]+["workers2."+col for col in workers2.columns]).show()